# JavaScript debugger; statement doesn't work even if breakpoints are enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I have a weird behavior in my application or browser or both. The `debugger` statement doesn't seem to work. It doesn't stop at that statement. However, when I put a breakpoint from dev tools, instead of `debugger` statement, it stops at that breakpoint. Dev tools is open and breakpoints are enabled. I haven't seen anything such this before.

I don't have any idea what causing this but I think that it is because of some sort of configuration in the project. Because my teammates also isn't able to make `debugger` statement work and we are working on same project.

Where should I check? Or is there any function or method in javascript that can disable `debugger` statements? We are using google chrome (Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and angularjs project (v1.4).

Comment: are you using any Js build tools like webpack or gulp/grunt ?

Comment: @vijay22uk Yes. We use both. Webpack and gulp.

Comment: webpack drops debugger statement, you have to check config and set drop_debugger to false explicitly. [link] (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/679)

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally set "Pause on Exceptions" to all/uncaught exceptions.

Go to the "Sources" tab. At the bottom toolbar, toggle the button that looks like the pause symbol surrounded by a circle (6th button from the left) until the color of the circle turns black to turn it off.

May this helps you !